# What is the meaning of getNumberOfUniqueHosts in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

In the hadoop packages mapred, the `org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskTrackerManager.java`, what is the meaning of this method?

```
/**
* @return The number of unique hosts running tasktrackers.
*/
public int getNumberOfUniqueHosts();
```

What does "unique hosts" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Actually "**TaskTrackerManager.java**" interface is used to manage information about the TaskTrackers running on a cluster.

```
public int getNumberOfUniqueHosts();
```

**This method used for:**

At a time many MapReduce jobs may run in a cluster. To identify the each task we refer that using Unique host id.

**For Example:** To get the task running in cluster we use like below

```
Task t = job.obtainNewMapTask(taskTracker, numTaskTrackers,
taskTrackerManager.getNumberOfUniqueHosts());
if (t != null) {
return Collections.singletonList(t);
```

For View the Hierarchy of `getNumberOfUniqueHosts();` method [CLICK HERE](http://www.havoozacademy.org/hadoop_uml/0.20.2/Documentation/html/da/d17/interfaceorg_1_1apache_1_1hadoop_1_1mapred_1_1_task_tracker_manager.html)

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Is it means a node? In the JobTracker， it maintenances a datastructure, Map<String,Integer>uniqueHostsMap， what's the usage of String and Integer? thank you very much